# Try/Except Not Catching Error

Tags: python, numpy, error-handling, try-catch

I'm trying to use try/except to take care of a divide by zero error, but the except doesn't seem to be catching the error and I can't figure out why.

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[0.5,0,0.25,0.125,0.05],[0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5]])
Y = np.array([[0,1,0,1,1],[0,0,0,0,1]])
p = np.shape(A)[0]
q = np.shape(A)[1]
m = 2
try:
    dA = (-1 / m) * ((Y - A) / (A - np.square(A))) * (A * (1 - A)) 
except Exception:
    dA = np.zeros((p,q))
```

It returns a divide by zero error and an invalid value encountered in multiply (because of the divide by zero error), but it kills the program instead of doing what's in except.

```
RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
  dA = (-1 / m) * ((Y - A) / (A - np.square(A))) * (A * (1 - A))
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply
  dA = (-1 / m) * ((Y - A) / (A - np.square(A))) * (A * (1 - A))
```

I tried specifying the error instead of just Exception, but that doesn't work either. What else could be the problem?

Comment: You have perhaps a divide by zero in np.zeros?

Comment: can you create a [mcve]? this sounds surprising

Comment: @GerardH.Pille: Hardly: `np.zeros` just creates a 0 filled matrix

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre is right, we don't know the values of your variables and adding the specific tracebacks to the question could be useful too.

Comment: If what you divide by is not standard python 0. but numpy 0. it only throws "RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide" but not error.

Comment: @edit that's why we need a [mcve]. I'm tired of questions stating that "python is not working".

Comment: It is a RuntimeWarning: divide by zero, I didn't think this wouldn't raise an exception though. Would I then define a new exception for this?

Comment: @LunarLlama, as said above without minimal, complete example, its not possible to say. It will also help you debug yourself and you may find solution yourself.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I added the rest of my variables; I'm just testing a part of a larger program that seems to not be working, so I didn't think they'd be that important, but thanks for catching me on this.

Answer (score 3):

Division by zero if it is numpy array does not throw Exception, but only gives warning and gives inf values.

You can use `numpy.isfinite` to check if values in the array are finite (and not nan or inf).

```
A = np.array([[0.5,0,0.25,0.125,0.05],[0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5]])
Y = np.array([[0,1,0,1,1],[0,0,0,0,1]])
p = np.shape(A)[0]
q = np.shape(A)[1]
m = 2
try:
    dA = (-1 / m) * ((Y - A) / (A - np.square(A))) * (A * (1 - A)) 
except Exception:
    dA = np.zeros((p,q))

if not np.isfinite(dA).all():
    dA = np.zeros((p,q))
```

If you are certain your elements are numpy arrays, you don't need exception:

```
dA = (-1 / m) * ((Y - A) / (A - np.square(A))) * (A * (1 - A)) 
if not np.isfinite(dA).all():
    dA = np.zeros((p,q))
```